# Is this a comma splice or something?

Tags: commas

From an essay I'm writing:

> The words demoniacal corpse, suggest that the creature is unnatural and unhuman. It creates an image of an evil monster, existing only to cause misery to mankind, which is quite the opposite of what the creature intends to do.

Comment: Maybe it's just an error? Shouldn't it read "The words 'demoniacal corpse' suggest that the creature is unnatural and unhuman"?

Comment: i meant the next part. I didnt mean to put one on the first part

Comment: You probably want to write *inhuman*.  It's a lot more common: http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=40676859

Comment: But "unhuman" is a little more powerful because it's not so common.  It slows down the brain a tiny bit, for a moment.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a comma splice.  A comma splice is a term for joining two (unrelated or unlike) sentences together with a comma without adding any kind of conjunction:

> Clowns wear funny noses, I don't like pie.

What you've done is place a comma between a verb and its subject, which is in most cases not allowed.  Just get rid of the comma:

> The words *demoniacal corpse* suggest that the creature is unnatural and **in**human.

Commas in this position are occasionally used to avoid misinterpretation or make a sentence easier to read:

> Most of those who can, work at home.
>   (*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, p.1730)

Here, the comma prevents you from misreading *work at home* as part of the subject and then getting confused when the sentence ends early.  But outside of exceptions like this, commas are almost always a bad idea between a verb and its subject.

Comment: What about the next part? It creates an image of an evil monster, existing only to cause misery to mankind, which is quite the opposite of what the creature intends to do.

Comment: @BrianTipold Those commas are both fine.